# Meteor: set values to the fields in page after redirecting to that page

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a button and onclick it redirects to the page which contains some fields and I want to insert values to those fields.

My onclick event:

```
'click .editPost':function()
{
    console.log(this._id);
    $('input[name="location"]').val("ls");
    Router.go('postSubmit');
}
```

I'm redirecting to the page but the value is not inserted to the field.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the rendered function for your template. You cannot modify the html within your template before it is rendered.

You could do something like this:

```
Template.postSubmit.rendered = function() {
  $('input[name="location"]').val('ls');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a session variable (which will hold state when changing routes).  Then you can set the field after the template has rendered with the stored session value.

**Templates**

```
<template name="postSubmit">
    <input name="location" value="">
</template>
```

**Event Handler**

```
'click .editPost':function() {
    // grab the input value
    var inputData = "ls";
    // store it in a session variable
    Session.set('locationValue', inputData);
    Router.go('postSubmit');
}
```

**Rendered Function**

```
Template.postSubmit.rendered = function() {
    $('input[name="location"]').val(Session.get('locationValue'));
}
```

Comment: i have 15 values like that,i think it is not recommended to set and get 15 session variables

Comment: Honestly it depends on your data -- Session variables are basically just reactive objects.  You could store one object containing all 15 values in a Session variable and delete it when you're done with it. Or you could namespace your Session keys. Could you clarify in your question what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: ,i have a form with nearly 15 fields.Whenever the owner of the form clicks the edit button already inserted data must autofill  the form to make things easy

Comment: So you're just carrying text from one view to another?

Answer (score 1):

are you looking to do something like this?

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/use-deps-dependency-instead-of-session-if-you-can